# Several days passed / had passed before Jeff worked up

Tags: tense

I came across this sentence:

> Several days passed before Jeff worked up enough courage to return to the house.

Isn't this sentence grammatically incorrect? Doesn't we need to use **had** after *several days* just like we used in  the below given sentence:

> The patient had died before the doctor came.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need it. You use the past perfect `Had+past participle` to indicate that one event took place before another in the past. But in the OP's  example, it's clear that *the several days passed **before** Jeff worked up enough courage to return to the house*. Similar to the other sentence, the subordinate conjunction "before" is sufficient to indicate that he had died before the doctor came.

At any rate, *past perfect* is not forbidden here; it's just not required.

Comment: Not required even in second sentence ?

Comment: @user212388 Yes, by the same token.

Comment: With the conjunction *before*, the sequence of events is clear. However, sometimes the past perfect is still used with *before*. I once read an answer to my question but I do not have the faintest idea now. In the case of 'several days' sentence above, what difference would the past perfect do if it was used by the author?

Comment: @MarkHubbard Ahh, how can I overlook the sloppiness. What a shame! Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: @learner I would say it makes no difference.

Comment: The past perfect isn't used to indicate that one event took place before another; that's simply the consequence of the *real* intent, which is to set up context for some past event, which will inevitably take place in the further past.